# Modx evolution white page with the word error in upper left hand corner

Tags: modx-evolution

Hi I have recently taken over a project using modx evolution. When I load the site i receive a blank white page with the word error in the upper left hand corner. I checked the error logs but they don't mention anything. Its an internal 500 error. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. Check modx_event_log table in your database for a php error message. For me this was 'modx_site_content' table does not exist. Had some problem with a backup server restore problem.